# Dynamic LINQ Method to return List of different Items from two lists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I want to write dynamic LINQ function to return the different between two lists but in abstraction way to make this function take any two lists of the same type and return the items that is the first list but not in the second one

I write some thing like the below and it is working fine but as I mention above I need it in abstraction way

```
List<Employee> a  = List of Items; 
List<Employee> b  = List of Items;
var finalCountries = a.Where(u => !b.Any(u2 => u2.ISOA2 == u.ISOA2)).ToList();
```

I read about dynamic LINQ expression but it is complex and I have no luck to find what I am looking to

if there are any way to write the above where statement as string and execute it?

Comment: You just need to either inherit or use an interface and make sure the type has `ISOA2` because your code needs it. Then you can make your method generic and use the `where` constraint on your method so only those types which have that property can be sent to your method.

Comment: ISOA2 is the key from EntityFramework I can get it for any entity type...and this is why I am asking here...can I write the above as string and execute it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enumerable.Except like this

```
List<Employee> a; 
List<Employee> b;
var finalCountries = a.Except(b).ToList();
```

If you need to compare your Employees by some field and this is not implemented by Employee you can use a custom comparer. For example [this one](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/LINQ-Your-Collections-with-IEqualityComparer-and-Lambda-Expressions). When your code can look like:

```
var comparer = new LambdaComparer<Employee>((emp1,emp2)=>emp1.ISOA2 == emp2.ISOA2);
var finalCountries = a.Except(b,comparer).ToList();
```

LambdaComparer code for convenience:

```
class LambdaComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    readonly Func<T, T, bool> _lambdaComparer;
    readonly Func<T, int> _lambdaHash;

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer) :
        this(lambdaComparer, o => 0){}

    public LambdaComparer(Func<T, T, bool> lambdaComparer, Func<T, int> lambdaHash)
    {
        _lambdaComparer = lambdaComparer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lambdaComparer));
        _lambdaHash = lambdaHash ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lambdaHash));
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y) => _lambdaComparer(x, y);
    public int GetHashCode(T obj) => _lambdaHash(obj);
}
```

**update:**

To make your method generic you can implement [IEquatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface in each of your entity types and use Except overload without parameters.

Comment: I used the Enumerable.Except but it is compare the whole object but I want to compare one field and this field is different from list to another, this filed will be a primary key for an entity...that is why I want to write the query as string

Comment: @ADA, check the LamdaComparer part, it allows comparing by any condition

Comment: But I don't know what is the condition will be...some times emp1.ISOA2 == emp2.ISOA2 another time dept1.ID == dept2.ID and so on

Comment: You can implement IEquatable interface in each of you data types this will do the trick